# Create a new node with the given parameter info & add a new node

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a constructor, destructor, a function that returns to the head of the Linked list. I am not sure about the createNode function and couldn't figure out how to do the addNode function.

//constructor

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
head = NULL;
}
```

//destructor

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
struct Node *temp = head;
int nodeCount = 0;
struct Node *nextNode;
while (temp != NULL)
{
    nextNode = temp->next;
    delete temp;
    nodeCount++;
    temp = nextNode;
}
head = NULL;
cout << "The number of deleted nodes is: " << nodeCount << "\n";
}
```

//This function returns the head of the linked list

```
Node *LinkedList::getHead()  
{
return head;
}
```

//This function creates a new node with the given parameter info. It returns a pointer that points to the newly created node.

```
Node * LinkedList::createNode(string name, int winScore, int loseScore)
{

Node *temp = new Node;
temp->name = name;
temp->winScore = winScore;
temp->loseScore = loseScore;
temp->next = NULL;

return new Node; // I think I have done this function right but please correct me if I'm wrong
}
```

//The function calls createnode first. It then insert the newly created node inside the linked list in alphabetical order. It also returns a pointer that 
points to the newly added node.

```
Node *LinkedList::addNode(string name, int winScore, int loseScore)
{
 //add code here which I couldn't do
}
```

Comment: `addNode` will allocate a new node, set the data value and `next` pointer to `NULL` then check if `head = NULL` (if so just set `head = newnode;` for the 1st node case), then your `else` case will use a temporary pointer set to head and then iterate `while (iter->next != NULL)` when that loop fails, `iter` points to the last node, so just set `iter->next = newnode;` (there are many many examples of the logic) Also, if you keep a `last` pointer, you can avoid iterating to find the last node -- up to you. (you can have separate `createNode` and `addNode` functions - or combine them, up to you)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin could you write it out for me? I am still confused. been trying for half an hour since you replied. I really want the code to have separate createNode and addNode functions

Comment: Sure give me a bit and I'll help you through it.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll hold up

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists are somewhat generic. With a simple implementation, you create a class instance for the list and the constuctor does nothing more than set the first node (`head`) of the list to `NULL`. (you can overload your constructor to take character data and call `insert` as well)

You start with your data structure (or class, your choice):

```
struct node_t {     /* simple struct holding char and next pointer */
    char data;
    node_t *next;
};
```

The `insert` function always creates and allocates storage for a new node and initializes the `next` pointer `NULL`, e.g.

```
class linkedlist {

    node_t *head, *iter;            /* private members */

  public:
    linkedlist() {                  /* constructor - sets head NULL */
        head = NULL;
    }
    ...
    node_t *insert (char data) {

        node_t *node = new node_t;  /* allocate new node */

        node->data = data;          /* set node data */
        node->next = NULL;
        ...
```

At this point in `insert`, all that remains is checking whether `head == NULL`, and if so, you know this is your first node, so simply set `head = node;`, e.g.

```
        if (!head)                  /* if 1st node */
            head = node;
```

If `head != NULL`, then you know you need to set `iter = head;` and iterate to the list-end to set the `last->next = node;`. You can do this with a simple `while` loop, e.g.

```
        else {              /* otherwise */
            iter = head;
            while (iter->next)      /* traditional iterate to find last */
                iter = iter->next;
            iter->next = node;      /* set new last */
        }
```

That's basically it other than returning a pointer to `node`. However, if you keep a `last` pointer, and always set `last = node;` at the end of your `insert` function, then there is no need to iterate to find the last node, you simply set `last->next = node;` instead of iterating and then update `last = node;`

A short example putting it altogether may help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node_t {     /* simple struct holding char and next pointer */
    char data;
    node_t *next;
};

class linkedlist {

    node_t *head, *iter;            /* private members */

  public:
    linkedlist() {                  /* constructor - sets head NULL */
        head = NULL;
    }
    ~linkedlist() {                 /* destructor - free list memory */
        iter = head;

        while (iter) {
            node_t *victim = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
            delete victim;
        }
    }

    node_t *insert (char data) {

        node_t *node = new node_t;  /* allocate new node */

        node->data = data;          /* set node data */
        node->next = NULL;

        if (!head)                  /* if 1st node */
            head = node;
        else {              /* otherwise */
            iter = head;
            while (iter->next)      /* traditional iterate to find last */
                iter = iter->next;
            iter->next = node;      /* set new last */
        }

        return node;                /* return node */
    }

    void print (void) {             /* simple print function */
        iter = head;
        while (iter) {
            cout << iter->data;
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main (void) {

    string s = "my dog has fleas";
    linkedlist l;

    for (auto& c : s)
        l.insert(c);

    l.print();
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_insert
my dog has fleas
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

Always use a memory/error checking program to verify you haven't done anything bizarre with your allocations and to confirm you have freed all the memory you allocate. For Linux, `valgrind` is the normal choice. Just run your program through it:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ll_insert
==9240== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9240== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9240== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9240== Command: ./bin/ll_insert
==9240==
my dog has fleas
==9240==
==9240== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9240==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9240==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 18 frees, 73,001 bytes allocated
==9240==
==9240== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9240==
==9240== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9240== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. I'll leave the `last` pointer implementation to you.

**Adding a Separate `create` Node Function**

You have the flexibility to decide how you want to factor your code into separate function. A `create` function normally just handles allocating for the `node` and setting the `data` values and initializing `next` to `NULL`. I'm not sure how much that makes things easier here, but where you have a complex `create` function, it does help tidy up the `insert` function a great deal.

Here you simply move the call to `new` and assignment to `data` and `next` to the new `create` function and call `create` at the top of `insert`, e.g.

```
    node_t *create (char data) {    /* simply move allocation/initialization
                                       to a create function */
        node_t *node = new node_t;  /* allocate new node */

        node->data = data;          /* set node data */
        node->next = NULL;

        return node;
    }

    node_t *insert (char data) {

        node_t *node = create (data);   /* call create function */

        if (!head)                  /* if 1st node */
            head = node;
        else {              /* otherwise */
            iter = head;
            while (iter->next)      /* traditional iterate to find last */
                iter = iter->next;
            iter->next = node;      /* set new last */
        }

        return node;                /* return node */
    }
```

It is functionally identical to doing it all in `insert` (and a smart compiler will probably optimize it identically as well). So it is entirely up to you what makes it easier to understand.

Comment: as much as I appreciate this explanation, could you modify my code accordingly create and add a new node in different functions. That would help me more, I think. Thanks.

Comment: And also, it is a bit ambiguous whether you wanted to have to call a separate `list.create()` before calling `list.insert (data)` in `main()` or whether you just wanted `create` as a helper for `insert` (which is what I did above). Since you provide a constructor to set `head = NULL;`, there really isn't a need for a separate function just to allow a call to `list.create()` where a list is needed. Let me know which you meant.

Comment: AAHHH I GOT IT TO WORK. OMG THANK YOU. I actually understood this now!!! aah i can't thank you enouugh!!

Comment: quick question: in the create function, if there is more than one data, then do i need to set the node data for every one of them right? example: 
Node * LinkedList::createNode(string name, int winScore, int loseScore)
{
 
 Node *node = new Node;
 node->name = name;
 node->winScore = winScore;
 node->loseScore = loseScore;
 node->next = NULL;

 return node;
}

Comment: Yep -- you GOT IT! If you have `node_t create (char c, int i, double d)` then you would set each member of the struct to `c, i, d` after you allocate! That IS one of the benefits of a separate create. You can focus simply on the initialization and assignment of the new struct member -- before worrying about the insert. (you still have to pass the same parameters through `insert` so they can be passed to `create` -- but you have that picture down fine)